# Как красиво привести класс к реализуемому им интерфейсу но не в момент его создания класса

Tags: c#, ооп, классы, шаблоны-проектирования, интерфейс

Есть код в котором есть вот такая реализация:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp{

    public interface IModel { } 

    public class Model : IModel { }

    public interface IDataBuilder<T> where T : IModel
    {
        T Build();
    }

    public interface IActionBuilder<T> where T : IModel
    {
        object BuildAction(T model);
    }

    public interface ISet<T> where T : IModel
    {
        IDataBuilder<T> DataBuilder { get; } 
        IActionBuilder<T> ActionBuilder { get;}
    }

    public class Builder
    {
        private List<ISet<IModel>> _dataBuilders;
        public void AddSet(ISet<IModel> _dataBuilder)
        {
            _dataBuilders.Add(_dataBuilder);
        }
    }

    public class MySet : ISet<Model>
    {
        public IDataBuilder<Model> DataBuilder => throw;    
        public IActionBuilder<Model> ActionBuilder  => throw;
    } 

    public class Program 
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = new Builder(); 
            builder.AddSet( new MySet() );
        }      
    }   
}
```

И на выходе в строчке

```
builder.AddSet( new MySet() );
```

я получаю такую ошибку:

> Program.cs(56, 29): [CS1503] Argument 1: cannot convert from
>   'ConsoleApp.MySet' to 'ConsoleApp.ISet'

Естественно я могу просто напрямую привести:

```
var builder = new Builder(); 
builder.AddSet( (ISet<IModel>)new MySet() );
```

Но в моем случае это не выход, мне нужно чтобы это архитектурно без такого приведения работало.

Поиграться с ковариантностью и инвариантностью пока не помогло к сожалению.

Comment: Интерфейсы никогда не реализовывали классы.

Comment: Переформулировал вопрос, я не имел в виду что интерфейс класс реализует, и вроде по коду это очевидно.

Comment: Ваши данные должны иметь именно тип который вы передали в метод, т.е. просто объявите переменную с типом который вам необходим, запишите туда ваши данные и передайте их в метод, тогда проблем не будет. Или же сделайте универсальный метод который будет принимать тип `Т`, на основе входных данных, и так же не забудьте установить ограничение типа. `where T : ISet<IModel>, MySet`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет, так не выйдет. `MySet` не реализует `ISet<IModel>`.

Вам нужно по сути, чтобы `ISet<Model>` являлось `ISet<IModel>`. Но это нарушило бы вариантность `T` в `IActionBuilder`.

Действительно, если бы ваш код компилировался,
то вы могли бы написать в `Builder.AddSet(ISet<IModel> _dataBuilder)`:

```
_dataBuilder.ActionBuilder.BuildAction(new AnotherModel());
```

для класса `public class AnotherModel : IModel { }`. То есть в `MySet.ActionBuilder.BuildAction` (cигнатура которого `object BuildAction(Model model);`) попал бы экземпляр `AnotherModel` на вход.

Вот почему `MySet` **не** реализует `ISet<IModel>`. Привести силой не удастся, вы получите исключение.

---

Корень проблемы — в интерфейсе `ISet<T>`. В нём параметр `T` используется как ковариантным (в `IDataBuilder<T>`), так и контравариантным (в `IActionBuilder<T>`) образом. Поэтому `T` в `ISet<T>` может быть лишь инвариантным.

Comment: Ну код в целом можно немного поменять, просто вот тут `builder.AddSet( (ISet<IModel>) new MySet() );` не хочется приводить.
Я понимаю почему не может привести но пока не придумал как решить это.

Comment: @Alex: Нет, проблема не решаема. Ручное приведение упадёт в рантайме.